# Display a div content as row while parent is displayed as column

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm now working on a problem for a few hours (not that experienced :D) and right now I'm pretty close, but theres a last thing not working:

I have **multiple divs** with different orientations in each other. An inner **parent div has flex-direction: column;** and the **child has flex-direction: row;** but its **not shown inline.**

JSFiddle Link: [Live Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/zd1LtLa8/5/)

---

### HTML

```
<div class="flexcon_game">
  <div class="flexcon_game_left">
    Left
  </div>
  <div class="flexcon_game_center">
    <div class="flexcon_game_center_top">
       center_top
    </div>
  <div class="flexcon_game_center_mid">
    <p> (-- </p>
    <p> -:- </p>
    <p> --) </p>
  </div>
  <div class="flexcon_game_center_bottom">
    center_bottom
  </div>
</div>
<div class="flexcon_game_right">
   right
</div>
```

### CSS

```
.flexcon_game{
   width: 80%;
   margin: auto;
   display: flex;
   flex-wrap: nowrap;
   justify-content: space-around;
   align-items: center;
 }
.flexcon_game_left{
   background-color: red;
 }
.flexcon_game_right{
    background-color: green;
 }
.flexcon_game_center{
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-around;
    background-color: orange;
 }
 .flexcon_game_center_mid{
     flex-flow: row nowrap;
 }
```

Comment: I think your original question title was better. It was more specific about what you wanted to do.

Comment: Ok. Thank you - Its working ;) and im happy again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Paragraphs are block level elements. Setting the flex direction to row doesn't change that. You have to explicitly make them inline in your CSS:

```css
.flexcon_game{
   width: 80%;
   margin: auto;
   display: flex;
   flex-wrap: nowrap;
   justify-content: space-around;
   align-items: center;
 }
.flexcon_game_left{
   background-color: red;
 }
.flexcon_game_right{
    background-color: green;
 }
.flexcon_game_center{
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-around;
    background-color: orange;
 }
 .flexcon_game_center_mid{
     flex-flow: row nowrap;
 }
 
 .flexcon_game_center_mid p{
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexcon_game">
  <div class="flexcon_game_left">
    Left
  </div>
  <div class="flexcon_game_center">
    <div class="flexcon_game_center_top">
       center_top
    </div>
  <div class="flexcon_game_center_mid">
    <p> (-- </p>
    <p> -:- </p>
    <p> --) </p>
  </div>
  <div class="flexcon_game_center_bottom">
    center_bottom
  </div>
</div>
<div class="flexcon_game_right">
   right
</div>
```